# What is the correct way to use boost::qi::rule with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-fusion

I am attempting to get a qi::rule<> to emit a struct with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT based on the boost employee example.

I have the following struct and its associated fusion macro:

```
struct LineOnCommand
{
   int lineNum;
   std::vector<char> humpType;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
   LineOnCommand,
   (int, lineNum)
   (std::vector<char>, humpType)
)
```

The associated parsing rules are:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> ascii::space_type> humpIdentifer = qi::lit("BH") | qi::lit("DH");

qi::rule<Iterator, LineOnCommand(), ascii::space_type> Cmd_LNON = qi::int_ >> -humpIdentifier >> qi::lit("LNON");
```

I then have a compound rule, of which all others (including this simple test case) are a part which is passed to the parser:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, qi::unused_type, ascii::space_type> commands =
   +( /* other rules | */ Cmd_LNON /*| other rules */);

bool success = qi::phrase_parse(StartIterator, EndIterator, commands, ascii::space);
```

The problem comes when I attempt to compile, and I get the error:

```
<boostsource>/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp(152): error: no suitable constructor exists to convert form "const int" to "LineOnCommand"
    attr = static_cast<Attribute>(val);
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. If I understand the way spirit works, the 2nd argument to the template of the rule represents the attribute (i.e. the data type emitted by the rule), and the BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT macro will adapt my struct so that boost knows how to convert a stream that is "int, std::vector" to it.

The only difference between what I'm doing here and the boost employee example is that I'm not using an explicit grammar to do the parsing. My understanding is this is not necessary, and that a rule by itself is sufficient.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is generally preferrable to post separate questions if your questions are essentially unrelated. In this case, they are.

Comment: Try making the example self-contained. This makes it a lot easier for people to help (I think the SO frequenters well-versed with Spirit enough to bake this into working code can be counted on the fingers of one hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure. I think I'm missing the problem. Perhaps, I "naturally" sidestep the problem because your sample is not self-contained.

So, here's my take on it: **See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79b4d8dabefc980c)**, in the hope that just comparing things helps you:

- I fixed the obvious typos in your rule declaration
- I suggested something other than `qi::unused_type`; if there's no attribute, there's no need to state it; beyond the iterator type, the template arguments to `qi::rule` and `qi::grammar` *are not positional*. So

  ```
  qi::rule<It, qi::unused_type(), ascii::space_type> r;
  qi::rule<It, ascii::space_type, qi::unused_type()> r;
  qi::rule<It, ascii::space_type> r;
  ```

  are all /logically/ equivalent.

Full listing:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct LineOnCommand
{
   int lineNum;
   std::vector<char> humpType;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
   LineOnCommand,
   (int, lineNum)
   (std::vector<char>, humpType)
)

template <typename It, typename Skipper = ascii::space_type>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, std::vector<LineOnCommand>(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(commands)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        humpIdentifier = string("BH") | string("DH");
        Cmd_LNON       = int_ >> -humpIdentifier >> "LNON";

        commands       = +( /* other rules | */ Cmd_LNON /*| other rules */ );
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<char>(),          Skipper> humpIdentifier;
    qi::rule<It, LineOnCommand(),              Skipper> Cmd_LNON;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<LineOnCommand>(), Skipper> commands;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iterator;
    parser<Iterator> p;

    std::string const input = 
        "123 BH LNON\n"
        "124 LNON\t\t\t"
        "125 DH LNON\n"
        "126 INVALID LNON";

    auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    std::vector<LineOnCommand> data;
    bool success = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, ascii::space, data);

    std::cout << "success:" << std::boolalpha << success << ", " 
              << "elements: " << data.size() << "\n";

    if (success)
    {
        for (auto& el : data)
        {
            std::cout << "Item: " << el.lineNum << ", humpType '" << std::string(el.humpType.begin(), el.humpType.end()) << "'\n";
        }
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    return success? 0 : 1;
}
```

Output:

```
success:true, elements: 3
Item: 123, humpType 'BH'
Item: 124, humpType ''
Item: 125, humpType 'DH'
Trailing unparsed: '126 INVALID LNON'
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, it's definitely moved me forward from where I was stuck. However, I'm finding that the hump variable in the LineOnCommand struct is not getting populated (it's just an empty vector). If I understand the way compounded rules work, in your example it should be filled with "DH," "BH," or "INVALID." Is this correct?

Comment: @stix Ah. Sorry, I missed that. `lit` exposes no attribute. Use `string` instead: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79b4d8dabefc980c)**