# Boost X3. Get rid of identity lambda to propagate attribute to value

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm migrating my code from Boost Qi to X3. I have non-terminal rule `expression` that is compiling to structure `ast::Expression`. For the minimal reproducing example I left 2 statements that forms `expression`. `value` creates new while `'(' expression ')'` should allow use brackets and just propogate result of `expression` to parent definition.

In the Qi I had `%=` operator that copied attribute to value. So the question - how to get rid of lambda `e2e` in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast
{
    enum class Cmd  : int
    {
        const_val = 42
    };
    using data_t = x3::variant<int, double>;
    struct Expression
    {
        Cmd _cmd;
        std::string _args;
    };
}//ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Expression, _cmd, _args)



inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const ast::Expression& val)
{
    os << "{" << (int)val._cmd << ':' << val._args << "}";
    return os;
}


namespace client
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::rule<class expression, ast::Expression> const expression("expression_stmt");
    x3::rule<class value, ast::data_t> const value("value_stmt");

    auto const value_def =
        x3::int_
        | x3::double_
        ;

    // construct expression form plain constant
    auto val_to_expr = [](auto& ctx) {
        auto& a1 = _attr(ctx);
        _val(ctx) = ast::Expression{ 
            ast::Cmd::const_val, 
            std::to_string(boost::get<int>(a1)) 
        };
        };

    // copy attribute to result value
    auto e2e = [](auto& ctx) {
        auto& a1 = _attr(ctx);
        _val(ctx) = a1;
        };

    auto const expression_def =
        value[val_to_expr]
// !!!! why I need e2e to copy attr to value?
        | ('(' > expression > ')') [e2e]
        ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expression, value);
}//ns:client

auto parse_text(const std::string& s)
{

    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    auto iter = s.cbegin();
    auto end_iter = s.cend();

    ast::Expression res;
    x3::ascii::space_type space;

    bool success = x3::phrase_parse(iter, end_iter,
        client::expression, space,
        res);
    if (success && iter == end_iter)
    {
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Parse failure\n{";
        while (iter != end_iter)
            std::cout << *iter++;
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    auto test = +[](const std::string& s) {
            std::cout << "parsing " << s << '\n';
            auto res = parse_text(s);
            std::cout << "'" << res << "'\n";
        };
    ;
    test("123");
    test("(123)");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `force_attribute` template argument on `x3::rule`:

```
x3::rule<class expression, ast::Expression, true> const expression{"expression"};
```

However, this means that all attribute assignments will be forced, so you have to facilitate `val_to_expr`. You easily can, using the relevant constructor:

```
struct Expression {
    Cmd         _cmd;
    std::string _args;

    Expression(value_t v = {}) //
        : _cmd(Cmd::const_val)
        , _args(std::to_string(get<int>(v))) {}
};
```

Also, in order for the constructor to be used, you should remove the Fusion adaptation, which you weren't using anyways. Now everything fits in roughly half the size of the code:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/133e782621aebd6a)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    using boost::get;
    enum class Cmd : int { const_val = 42 };
    using value_t = x3::variant<int, double>;

    struct Expression {
        Cmd         _cmd;
        std::string _args;

        Expression(value_t v = {}) //
            : _cmd(Cmd::const_val)
            , _args(std::to_string(get<int>(v))) {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Expression const& e) {
            os << "{" << static_cast<int>(e._cmd) << ':' << e._args << "}";
            return os;
        }
    };
} // namespace ast

namespace client {
    x3::rule<class expression, ast::Expression, true> const expression{"expression"};
    x3::rule<class value, ast::value_t> const               value{"value"};

    auto const value_def      = x3::int_ | x3::double_;
    auto const expression_def = value | ('(' > expression > ')');

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expression, value)
} // namespace client

std::optional<ast::Expression> parse_text(std::string_view s) {
    if (ast::Expression res;
        phrase_parse(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), client::expression >> x3::eoi, x3::space, res))
        return res;
    else
        return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
    for (std::string_view s : {"123", "(123)"})
        if (auto e = parse_text(s))
            std::cout << quoted(s) << " -> " << *e << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << quoted(s) << " failed\n";
}
```

Printing

```
"123" -> {42:123}
"(123)" -> {42:123}
```

### Bonus/Caveat

1. Ironically, at the end of that, you [no longer need `force_attribute`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f02c557f5542642d) to begin with, because you don't use any semantic actions (see [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)).
2. Also, the production `int_ | double_` will never match doubles (see e.g. [Why doesn't this boost::spirit::qi rule successfully parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369223/why-doesnt-this-boostspiritqi-rule-successfully-parse/23369473#23369473)).
3. It looks as though you're crafting the classical expression parser. As such, you'd very much expect values to ***be*** expressions:

   ```
   struct Command {
       enum Code : int { const_val = 42 };
       Code        _cmd;
       std::string _args;
   };

   using Expression = boost::variant<int, double, Command>;
   ```

   Now you can enjoy no-semantic-action Fusion adaptation bliss:

   ```
   x3::rule<class command, ast::Command>  const command{"command"};
   x3::rule<class expr,  ast::Expression> const expr{"expr"};

   auto dbl         = x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double>>{};
   auto value       = dbl | x3::int_;
   auto command_def = '(' > x3::attr(ast::Command::const_val) > x3::raw[value % ','] > ')';
   auto expr_def    = command | value;
   ```

   Printing [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa0b02378319f717):

   ```
   "123" -> 123
   "(123)" -> {42:123}
   ```
4. Having reached this point, it would become more obvious that it is probably NOT necessary to put `_args` as a string. I bet you'd rather recurse with `std::vector<Expression>`?

   ```
   struct Command {
       enum Code : int { const_val = 42 };
       Code                    _cmd;
       std::vector<Expression> _args;
   };
   ```

   And a minor change of the `Command` rule:

   ```
   auto const command_def = '(' > x3::attr(ast::Command::const_val) > (expr % ',') > ')';
   ```

Now you can parse arbitrarily nested expressions, which do not even flatten to strings in the AST:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fca8feac68ad8aa)**

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    struct Command;
    using Expression = boost::variant<int, double, boost::recursive_wrapper<Command>>;

    struct Command {
        enum Code : int { const_val = 42 };
        Code                    _cmd;
        std::vector<Expression> _args;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<Expression> const& ee) {
            for (auto sep ="["; auto& e : ee)
                os << std::exchange(sep, ",") << e;
            return ee.empty() ? os : os << "]";
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Command const& e) {
            os << "{" << e._cmd << ':' << e._args << "}";
            return os;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Code const& c) {
            switch (c) {
                case const_val: return os << "const_val";
                default:        return os << "?";
            }
        }
    };

} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Command, _cmd, _args)

namespace client {
    x3::rule<class command, ast::Command>  const command{"command"};
    x3::rule<class expr,  ast::Expression> const expr{"expr"};

    auto const dbl         = x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double>>{};
    auto const value       = dbl | x3::int_;
    auto const command_def = '(' > x3::attr(ast::Command::const_val) > (expr % ',') > ')';
    auto const expr_def    = command | value;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(command, expr)
} // namespace client

std::optional<ast::Expression> parse_text(std::string_view s) {
    if (ast::Expression e;
        phrase_parse(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), client::expr >> x3::eoi, x3::space, e))
        return e;
    else
        return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
    for (std::string_view s : {
             "123",
             "(123)",
             "(123, 234, 345)",
             "(123, 234, (345, 42.7e-3), 456)",
         })
        if (auto e = parse_text(s))
            std::cout << std::setw(34) << quoted(s) << " -> " << *e << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << std::setw(34) << quoted(s) << " failed\n";
}
```

Printing:

```
                             "123" -> 123
                           "(123)" -> {const_val:[123]}
                 "(123, 234, 345)" -> {const_val:[123,234,345]}
 "(123, 234, (345, 42.7e-3), 456)" -> {const_val:[123,234,{const_val:[345,0.0427]},456]}
```

Comment: Wow, as usual very comprehensive and detailed answer, thank you! I spend almost 3 day figuring out why my code had not compiled when I applied you recomendation with constructor. It was appeared that I left in my code `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` - stupid mistake. Regarding `x3::int_|x3::double` - I intentionally put this simplified definition but isn't your definition `dbl` is overcomplex in this case? For example in my real code I just use `x3::uint_parser<std::int64_t, 10>()) >> !x3::lit('.'))
        | x3::double_` - should I worry about it?

Comment: What makes your proposition less complex? I don't see it. Mine just leverages existing code. Notes: your real part accepts negative numbers, whereas the integer part doesn't, I'm not sure that's on purpose. Your production also fails to treat the integral part as lexeme, which is different, but it happens not to interfere with useful expression in your simple grammar, I think. (By the way, it's a bit ironic that you didn't use `x3::[u]int_`? Isn't that... "overcomplex" :))

Comment: the reason is very simple - I have Cmd::negate, so it can be applied for multiple cases - not only for constant but for expressions as well.

Comment: Of course unary operators exist, so it's common place for grammars to have only positive literals. But then you'd probably require the same measure for `double_` (more reasons to implement policies). I'd say sample production is objectively simpler and more efficient. But I agree your take can work (if you add the `lexeme[]`) (you didn't address any of the complexity question)